# Why do I need to hardcode clauses in this subselect?

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I'm having a hard time understanding why this nested SELECT yields results that I thought I had explicitly excluded. What is my mistake?

This is a context of bank accounts.

**1) First,** I want to find those accounts that have a trailing blank in either of their two account number fields - that's simple enough. Note the `clientcode='FOO'` because the `accounts` table holds accounts from several banks, and I only want to see the `FOO` accounts:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts 
WHERE ClientCode = 'FOO'
AND (  AccountId LIKE '% ' OR AccountIdentNo LIKE '% ' )
```

**This is fine:** I see zero results because the only accounts with trailing blanks are in another bank `BAR`. If I set `clientcode='BAR'` then I see those accounts.

**2) Second,** I want to know whether any accounts exist with the same ID's but *without* trailing blanks. The results from 1) would later need to be merged into these.
That would be simple if there were only one ID column, but I have two so I have to do two sub-selects.
Also, note that I use `a2.ClientCode = a1.ClientCode` so I don't have redundant hard-coded values in my statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts a1
WHERE a1.ClientCode = 'FOO'
AND TRIM( AccountId ) IN
( SELECT AccountId FROM Accounts a2
  WHERE a2.ClientCode = a1.ClientCode
  AND (  a2.AccountId like '% ' OR a2.AccountIdentNo like '% ' )
) 
OR TRIM( AccountIdentNo ) IN
( SELECT AccountIdentNo FROM Accounts a3
  WHERE a3.ClientCode = a1.ClientCode
  AND (  a3.AccountId like '% ' OR a3.ACCOUNTIDENTNO like '% ' )
);
```

**This fails,** because I now get results from `BAR`?? Let's try hardcoding:

**3) Third,** I replace the `a2.ClientCode = a1.ClientCode` with actual hardcoded values in all three selects:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts a1
WHERE a1.ClientCode = 'FOO'
AND TRIM( AccountId ) IN
( SELECT AccountId FROM Accounts a2
  WHERE a2.ClientCode = 'FOO'
  AND (  a2.AccountId like '% ' OR a2.AccountIdentNo like '% ' )
) 
OR TRIM( AccountIdentNo ) IN
( SELECT AccountIdentNo FROM Accounts a3
  WHERE a3.ClientCode = 'FOO'
  AND (  a3.AccountId like '% ' OR a3.AccountIdentNo like '% ' )
);
```

**This works!** I get zero results for `FOO` and I get results if I use `BAR` instead.

**Question:**
Why in the world does 2) not work but 3) does? Why does this soft assignment not work and a hard value assignment works?

---

table Accounts:

```
ClientCode | AccountId | AccountIdentNo
---------------------------------------
'FOO'      | '111'     | '111'
'BAR'      | '222 '    | '222'
'BAR'      | '333'     | '333 '
'BAR'      | '444'     | '444'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a set of brackets in the second one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Accounts a1
WHERE a1.ClientCode = 'FOO'
    AND TRIM( AccountId ) IN (( 
        SELECT AccountId 
        FROM Accounts a2
        WHERE a2.ClientCode = a1.ClientCode
            AND (  a2.AccountId like '% ' OR a2.AccountIdentNo like '% ' )
    ) OR TRIM( AccountIdentNo ) IN ( 
        SELECT AccountIdentNo 
        FROM Accounts a3
        WHERE a3.ClientCode = a1.ClientCode
        AND (  a3.AccountId like '% ' OR a3.ACCOUNTIDENTNO like '% ' )
    ));
```

`OR` has a lower precedence than `AND`.  Without bracket, your `WHERE` becomes

```
WHERE (a1.ClientCode = 'FOO'
AND TRIM( AccountId ) IN (
    SELECT AccountId 
    FROM Accounts a2
    WHERE a2.ClientCode = a1.ClientCode
        AND (  a2.AccountId like '% ' OR a2.AccountIdentNo like '% ' )
)) OR TRIM( AccountIdentNo ) IN ( 
    SELECT AccountIdentNo 
    FROM Accounts a3
    WHERE a3.ClientCode = a1.ClientCode
    AND (  a3.AccountId like '% ' OR a3.ACCOUNTIDENTNO like '% ' )
);
```

Comment: I figured it was something tiny like this, but I just couldn't see it. Thank you!!